# Wordpress Parent-Child Pages Menu - Class on wp_list_pages?

Tags: php, css, wordpress

I have posted this same question a month ago, but I was lacking codes to make my words have a little more sense. So here's to a better and more organized one:

I'm having some trouble trying to understand how the parent-child pages menu works on wordpress. I have these codes:

a menu.php for the left sidebar (and I dont have anything for this specific file inside my functions.php):

```
<div class="col-md-3 dadin-menu">
  <ul class="nav nav-tabs nav-stacked dadin-menu-left">
    <li><a href="<?php echo get_bloginfo( 'wpurl' );?>">Home</a></li>
    <?php wp_list_pages('title_li=') ?>
    <li><a href="http://www.utfpr.edu.br" target="_blank" rel="noopener">UTFPR</a></li>
  </ul>
```

The pages are nested inside the menu tab on wordpress. The wp_list_pages pull those pages to show on the sidebar, but the problem is that I can't customize it properly with css. Just like the other two links (that are not inside the wp_list_page), I want it to be highlighted when hovered, but the pages inside the wp_list_pages will be highlighted as a single box/element, and not as single line elements. I know that this is confusing, so I tried to make more sense in this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/kxbo1g0h/37/. Here you can see that I created classes for each of the < ul >, and I can target them separately with css. No highlighting over all the elements on a specific nested list! But I do understand that this is not how it works with the wp_list_pages, so I just want a little help with how I can make what it's happening on the fiddle code to work with what I have on my menu.php file.

The blog, if you would like to take a look on how it's working right now and my work around to make highlight only single < a > blocks and not the whole nested children: http://dadin.ct.utfpr.edu.br/ What I have here kinda works, but the idea was for the highlight to take the whole line space inside its container, and not just a part of it.

And the link for my other question that have some "explanatory" images for what is happening and what I wanted it to look like: 
[Wordpress Parent-Child Pages Menu - background highlighted on list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50052619/wordpress-parent-child-pages-menu-background-highlighted-on-list)

Answer (score 0):

Use `ul ul` and `ul ul ul` to target children and grandchildren.
Or `ul > ul` to be more exact with the selector.

`ul ul` selects all uls that are within another ul,
`ul > ul` selects only those uls that are on the first level below the original ul.
See this for reference: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp

Here is your fiddle adjusted without classes to explain it better:

http://jsfiddle.net/kxbo1g0h/41/

```css
ul, li {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.container {
  padding: 0 15%;
}

.container h4 {
  padding-left: 0;
  font-size: 25px;
  font-family: arial;
}

.ul-container {
  padding: 0 10%;
}

ul a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #333;
}


ul li {
    padding-left: 15%;
    border: none;
    margin: 0 auto;
    list-style-type: none;
    font-size: 16px;
    padding-bottom: .3em;
    padding-top:.3em;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #CDCDCD;
    border-width: 15%; /*nao funciona*/
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

ul li:hover,
ul li:focus {
  background: #ccc;
  cursor: pointer;
}

ul > ul > li {
  background: none; 
  text-transform: lowercase;
/*  padding-left: 15%;
  display: block;*/
}

ul > ul > li:hover,
ul > ul > li:focus {
  background: #888;
  color: white;
  cursor: pointer;
}

ul > ul > li > a {
  padding-left: 15%;
}

ul > ul >ul >  li:hover,
ul > ul >ul > li:focus {
  background: red;
}

ul > ul >ul > li > a {
  padding-left: 30%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<h4>
Lista Menu
</h4>
</div>

<div class="ul-container">


<ul>
<li><a href="#">item 1</a></li>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">child 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">child 2</a></li>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">grandkid 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">grandkid 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">grandkid 3</a></li>
      </ul>
    <li><a href="#">child 3</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">child 4</a></li>
  </ul>
<li><a href="#">item 2</a></li>
<li><a href="#">item 3</a></li>
<li><a href="#">item 4</a></li>
</ul>

</div>
```

Comment: Hey! Thank you for explaining this, this was actually something that I didn't quite grasp before. It makes things so much more easier! But the thing is, just like I replied to Elvin Haci above, is that this works if I have a list of pages that doesn't include the wp_pages_list code, because it's more specific. This is why I was thinking if it would make sense (and if there is any way) of wrapping the code some how so I can input classes for the pages who have children, specifically? And not to use the output html generated from wp_pages_list

Comment: Could you elaborate more on your problem? Do you mean you have two pages, one where you have the wp_pages_list, where you want this code, and one that has uls and lis but not the wp_pages_list, where you do not want this code?

Answer (score 0):

Why not to use CSS?

f.e.

```
.dadin-menu-left ul>li>ul>li:hover {background:red !important}
```

this will colorify children li background.

```
.dadin-menu-left ul>li:hover {background:red !important}
```

this will colorify parent ones.

Comment: Hey! Thank you for taking the time to help me with this! 

This actually works, kind of... The problem is that it takes alway the hover on the other li, it only works on the pages who have children. I'm trying a whole combination of elements together, but I feel that the complication is coming from the wp_list_pages and how it works. Even when I try to target the specific output class for each parent of a li, I still cant make it to not override the hover on the other pages without children :t

Comment: Actually for advanced modification there is WALKER logic in WordPress which allows you to generate any custom layout with wp_list_pages, wp_list_categories. I just tried to go with easier way.

Comment: i don't understand what you mean by saying "it takes alway the hover on the other li, it only works on the pages who have children" - i wish i could understand what you mean